# values for drop down list if check box checked or unchecked according to checkbox value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a javascript code when user select multiple checkboxes, the checkbox id or value should be in a drop down. travel option in my example should be selected automatically according to the checkbox selection. need it in javascript

```html
<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="flight" data-input="00N8E000002AjRq" />
<label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="flight">
  <span class="form__label">Flight</span>
</label>

<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="hotel" />
<label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="hotel">
  <span class="form__label">Hotel</span>
</label>

<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="travel" />
<label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="travel">
  <span class="form__label">Transfer </span>
</label> Travel Options:
<select id="00N8E000002AjRq" name="00N8E000002AjRq" title="Travel Options">
  <option value="">--None--</option>
  <option value="Flight">Flight</option>
  <option value="Flight + Hotel">Flight + Hotel</option>
  <option value="Flight + Hotel + Transfer">Flight + Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Flight + Transfer">Flight + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Eurostar">Eurostar</option>
  <option value="Eurostar + Hotel">Eurostar + Hotel</option>
  <option value="Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer">Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Eurostar + Transfer">Eurostar + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Train">Train</option>
  <option value="Train + Hotel">Train + Hotel</option>
  <option value="Train + Hotel + Transfer">Train + Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
  <option value="Hotel + Transfer">Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Transfer">Transfer</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: I have added how it should be when user selected checkboxes under travel option dropdown.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? And can you share your JS code?

Comment: @StefanN check i posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the js code i tried

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
var inputValue = $(this).attr("id");
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("." + inputValue + " select").val(1);
} else {
    $("." + inputValue + " select").val(-1);
}
```

});

Comment: Add the code snippet you tried in the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I need the exact samething like below snippet, but instead of alert i need it in a drop down list. value or id should be in a drop down list.

```js
 function GetSelected() {
        //Create an Array.
        var selected = new Array();
 
        //Reference the Table.
        var tblFruits = document.getElementById("tblFruits");
 
        //Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
        var chks = tblFruits.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
 
        // Loop and push the checked CheckBox value in Array.
        for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
            if (chks[i].checked) {
                selected.push(chks[i].value);
            }
        }
 
        //Display the selected CheckBox values.
        if (selected.length > 0) {
            alert("Selected values: " + selected.join(","));
        }
    };
```

```html
<table id="tblFruits">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkMango" type="checkbox" value="1"/><label for="chkMango">Mango</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkApple" type="checkbox" value="2"/><label for="chkApple">Apple</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkBanana" type="checkbox" value="3"/><label for="chkBanana">Banana</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkGuava" type="checkbox" value="4"/><label for="chkGuava">Guava</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="chkOrange" type="checkbox" value="5"/><label for="chkOrange">Orange</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type = "button" value = "Get" onclick = "GetSelected()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do, there's probably much more efficient ways to do but since this you haven't tried anything else I guess it'll do.

```js
let selected = {};
let labels = [...document.querySelectorAll('label')].forEach((l) => {
 selected[l.getAttribute('for')] = false;
});
let dropdown = document.getElementById('00N8E000002AjRq');


const click_checkbox = (evt) => {

  const id = evt.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
   selected[id] = evt.currentTarget.checked;
   
   let select = '';
   for(let i of Object.keys(selected)) {
    if(selected[i]) select += i;
   }
   
   let found = false;
   let index = 0;
   [...dropdown.options].forEach( (d, i) => {
   
     if(d.value === select) {
        found = true;
        index = i;
        return;
     }
   });
   dropdown.selectedIndex = index;
   
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('.form__input--checkbox')].forEach( (i) => i.addEventListener('click', click_checkbox ));
```

```html
<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Flight" data-input="00N8E000002AjRq" />
                <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="Flight">
                                <span class="form__label">Flight</span>
                </label>

                <input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Hotel" />
                <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="Hotel">
                                <span class="form__label">Hotel</span>
                </label>

                <input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Transfer" />
                <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="Transfer">
                                <span class="form__label">Transfer </span>
                </label>





Travel Options:<select  id="00N8E000002AjRq"      name="00N8E000002AjRq" title="Travel Options"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Flight">Flight</option>
<option value="FlightHotel">Flight + Hotel</option>
<option value="FlightHotelTransfer">Flight + Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="FlightTransfer">Flight + Transfer</option>
<option value="Eurostar">Eurostar</option>
<option value="EurostarHotel">Eurostar + Hotel</option>
<option value="EurostarHotelTransfer">Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="EurostarTransfer">Eurostar + Transfer</option>
<option value="Train">Train</option>
<option value="TrainHotel">Train + Hotel</option>
<option value="TrainHotelTransfer">Train + Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
<option value="HotelTransfer">Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Transfer">Transfer</option>
</select><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple ES6 solution using a delegate change listener. Please note that for simplification reasons I've changed the `id="travel"` to `id="transfer"`:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('00N8E000002AjRq');

document.addEventListener('change', ({target}) => {
  // when a checkbox is changed
  if (['flight', 'hotel', 'transfer'].includes(target.id)) {
    // iterate over the select options
    [...select.options].forEach(option => {
      // and for each, decide whether it's hidden
      option.hidden = 
        (
          // if no box is checked, no option should be hidden
          !checkedBoxes().length 
          || 
          // otherwise, if NOT any of the lowercased values split by ' + ' 
          // occurs in checkedBoxes(), hide the option
          !option.value.toLowerCase().split(' + ').some(value => checkedBoxes().includes(value))
        )
        // but only if its value is not "" (first option) "--None--"
        && option.value !== "";
    })
  }
})

function checkedBoxes() {
  return [flight, hotel, transfer].filter(el => el.checked).map(el => el.id);
}
```

```html
<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="flight" data-input="00N8E000002AjRq" />
<label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="flight">
  <span class="form__label">Flight</span>
</label>

<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="hotel" />
<label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="hotel">
  <span class="form__label">Hotel</span>
</label>

<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="transfer" />
<label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="transfer">
  <span class="form__label">Transfer</span>
</label> 
<br />
Travel Options:
<select id="00N8E000002AjRq" name="00N8E000002AjRq" title="Travel Options">
  <option value="">--None--</option>
  <option value="Flight">Flight</option>
  <option value="Flight + Hotel">Flight + Hotel</option>
  <option value="Flight + Hotel + Transfer">Flight + Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Flight + Transfer">Flight + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Eurostar">Eurostar</option>
  <option value="Eurostar + Hotel">Eurostar + Hotel</option>
  <option value="Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer">Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Eurostar + Transfer">Eurostar + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Train">Train</option>
  <option value="Train + Hotel">Train + Hotel</option>
  <option value="Train + Hotel + Transfer">Train + Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
  <option value="Hotel + Transfer">Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Transfer">Transfer</option>
</select><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `change` event to all input with type `checkbox`, get all checked input, iterate over it to get the `id` attribute, convert the array of id's to string using join and then select the dropdown which match the joined id string.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
      const checkedInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
      const ids = [...checkedInputs].map((input) => input.id.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.id.slice(1));
      const joinedIds = ids.join(' + ');
      document.querySelector('select').value = joinedIds;
    });
  });
```

```html
<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="flight" data-input="00N8E000002AjRq" />
<label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="flight">
          <span class="form__label">Flight</span>
        </label>

<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="hotel" />
<label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="hotel">
          <span class="form__label">Hotel</span>
        </label>

<input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="travel" />
<label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="travel">
          <span class="form__label">Transfer </span>
        </label> Travel Options:
<select id="00N8E000002AjRq" name="00N8E000002AjRq" title="Travel Options">
  <option value="">--None--</option>
  <option value="Flight">Flight</option>
  <option value="Flight + Hotel">Flight + Hotel</option>
  <option value="Flight + Hotel + Travel">Flight + Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Flight + Travel">Flight + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Eurostar">Eurostar</option>
  <option value="Eurostar + Hotel">Eurostar + Hotel</option>
  <option value="Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer">Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Eurostar + Transfer">Eurostar + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Train">Train</option>
  <option value="Train + Hotel">Train + Hotel</option>
  <option value="Train + Hotel + Transfer">Train + Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
  <option value="Hotel + Transfer">Hotel + Transfer</option>
  <option value="Transfer">Transfer</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: you might want to change `id="travel"` to `id="transfer"` so that the 3rd checkbox does something